# Disable input so they are excluded from POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

I have a form posting values to the server, but i wish to be able to control which inputs are included as request parameters in the post.

So if i have a basic text input, how can I stop it getting included in the submit?

Comment: Lots of working answers, thanks a lot for your time everyone! Chose accepted answer based on upvotes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

for jquery 1.6 an higher do

```
$("#formField").prop("disabled",true);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could insert input fields with no "name" attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="something" />
```

Or you could simply remove them once the form is submitted (in jquery):

```
$("form").submit(function() {

   $(this).children('#something').remove();

});
```

if you omit the "name" attribute value you can't access that value through any method..

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just stumbled across this, but thought some clarification was needed at the end. Omitting the `name` attribute will prevent it from being accessed through any method on the server; however, you can still access it in javascript/jquery by its `id`, `class`, etc attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Generally if you do `jQuery("#{input id}").attr("disabled","disabled");` it should prevent it from being sent.

Answer (score 2):

You can just post the variables which you want. Use Jquery post,

```
 $.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
       function(data) {
         alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
       });
```